# how to create an app to Geo tag a video while recording video for field survey

Tags: android, gps

Recently i have created an android app for village information system that automatically captures GPS location, Geo tagged images and save other information in offline mode as well as online mode.

Now is there any solution to create an app to Geo tag a video while recording video for field survey or to capture latitude and longitude while recording vedio.

Answer (score 0):

If you already developed an app that geo tags images then it would be the same with video.
If you need to show coordinates while taking the video you could do something like this:

- using an activity to perform the video taking
- use a service to get the location(you could have it running for the whole time needed) and store it somewhere, maybe an app Singleton. You can then retrieve it periodically from wherever needed like the video taking activity

Comment: i have to show this location data in map also in moving manner..so i will try to do it..thank you very much for help.